# MCU: Whose blast weapon is more powerful?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-marvel, iron-man, thor

We saw that all three Super Heroes Captain Marvel, Iron Man and Thor Odinson have the same sort of weapons. Same because all three weapons look like energy beams (made up of photons, electrons, +ve -ve ions).

But which one is more powerful?

- Captain Marvel went through (destroyed) entire ship
- Thor has energy surge flowing through his entire body and weapon. He lands in Wakanda and swipes dead the entire army
- Iron Man easily able to tackle the same energy surge from Thor in `The Avengers (2012)`

and the last one (excuse me for asking a question inside a question),

Would Captain Marvel exhaust all her energy someday? Because it is just absorbed energy from a power core, nothing that she's been producing inside her body.

Comment: "Whose blast"? "Blast" is a very generic term, it can be bomb blast, Batman's Blast, Blast in War movies, why would people from MCU community come and answer this question. At first read, the right people will ignore it.

Comment: You're comparing completely three different entities, A Man, Norse god and Alien technology. whose powers are different from origin, how they work, and based on how they choose to use it and use it against or with someone. Stark has different beams, unibeam and common hand repulsors are most common. Thor possess/controls natural power of Thunder. while Danvers have Kree energy which we don't know much about, but it's photonic energy blast. So I'm not sure we could get a confirmed answer for this. anyway if you'd like, there are multiple quora articles on how each one's powers work and science

Comment: **"Whose blast"?**, it's included inside on your question. Just tried to make title summarized and point complete question into the question body. but if it's not good or as you expected, you can always revert it back. just curious, what's *Batman's Blast*?

Comment: I don't think so. Scientifically all are same (photon, electron, +ve -ve ions), that's why a Norse God's energy easily able completely charge human-made war suit and photon energy tickles humans with short teasers from Marvel's hand.

Comment: **Scientifically all are same**, okay. good luck..  just tried to help as I could, that's all

Comment: Batman's bomb blast :), he can throw bombs at you to blast you off. My point was to make specific to MCU and not for entire IMDB.

Comment: **Batman's bomb blast :)** dude, that's bomb's blast. if Batman blows up, then it can be called Batman's blast, not the other way around ;) . anyway, you can rever back to original post or edit as you'd like.

Comment: I guess moderator will come in few seconds and delete all fun comments. Anyways, Batman's blast is Batman's blast because Batman's blast is different than any other blast. Secondly, there is nothing I ever heard like "Bomb's blast" it is very new for me. I always knew that bomb blasted/exploded, never knew that bomb has its own blast like "bomb's blast". LOLZZZ

Comment: Slow down guys. These are comic book characters. I'm not sure you should try to rely on "real" science here.

Comment: It can be some science, not all the way full-blown science and the basis on that I guess it is all same. Had that not been true, how come Thor's energy recharged Iron Man body suit, recharged Jarvis' synthesis process?

Comment: *how come Thor's energy recharged Iron Man body suit, recharged Jarvis' synthesis process* Thunder <-> (electron flow) a.k.a electricity

Comment: I don't know "how come? Stark knows better but it is how it was shown in the movie. Better if you ask it as a seprate question so that people can upvote it. It won't be termed as opinion based, don't worry. LOL

Comment: Hey, same here. If you think that I am against you, then what made you think like that? You'll get your answer. BTW, why do you care, what do I think? Do you know me? Just chill man! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break it down for these characters, based on [Marvel statistics of March 11, 2019](https://www.marvel.com/articles/comics/why-captain-marvel-is-the-most-powerful-hero-in-the-marvel-universe-an-infographic).

## Iron Man:

```
- Speed:       7,620 miles/hour  
- Energy:      418,000,000,000,000+ joule
- Durability:  1,000,000,000,000,000 joules
- Strength:    200,000 pounds
```

## Captain Marvel:

```
- Speed:       240,000 miles/hour
- Energy:      418,000,000,000,000 joules
- Durability:  4,180,000,000,000,000 joules
- Strength:    400,000 pounds
```

## Thor:

```
- Speed:       640,600,000 miles/hour  
- Energy:      2,000,000,000,000,000 joules
- Durability:  3,86 * 10^26 joules
- Strength:    2,000,000,000,000,000 pounds
```

As you can see:

- Iron Man is just an **earth man** and relies on his suit. Which means he is slower, can't lift as much and can't take a punch like the other 2, but his energy output is on par with Captain Marvel.
- Captain Marvel is an **augmented earth woman**. Her Kree powers give her more durability and a higher speed and strength than Iron Man. But they both are somewhat equal in energy output.
- Thor is Norse **GOD**. He clearly outclasses the others in terms of speed (he can teleport), strength (lift a trillion ton) and durability (withstand the nonillion joule output of the heart of a star). His energy output is closer to the others in terms of absolute value, but it is still about 4-5 times higher than both Iron Man and Captain Marvel.

--- EDIT ---

The article linked is creating confusion for some.

As the title states that "Captain Marvel is the most '**powerful**' hero".
Unfortunately this is only to create a buzz. (The article was written for the Captain Marvel movie release and thus needed to give a boost to the character)
Because if you read the article and look at the data presented, you get a different conclusion.

A more correct title would have been "Captain Marvel is the **best overall** hero", but that doesn't have the same ring to it.

Why the best overall character? Because Captain Marvel is not the best in any field (Hulk is stronger, Thor is more durable, Iron Man is more intelligent, Captain America is a better strategist, ...), but she is always in the higher ranks in every field and thus overall beter.

Based on the article, I created the ranking per field for some of the most powerful heroes and added the winner per field for the 3 heroes of this question (Iron Man, Thor and Captain Marvel).

The question was about the most powerful energy blast and we can see that Thor is the winner for that category.

[image]

--- Edit 2 ---

> "Energy output for Cap being zero seems weird. compared to others, Hulk doesn't have any energy beam or anything, just like Cap. but him having a huge number and Cap having zero is unclear to me why."

Nor the Hulk nor Captain America have any energy beams or rays or anything like that.
But the difference is that the Hulk ... euhm ... *Hulks out*. Bruce Banner transforms into the Hulk and gets stronger and stronger as he gets angrier.
He goes from a weak man with a mass of 128 pounds (58 kilograms) to an indestructible behemoth weighing in at 1150 pounds (521 kilograms).
This change in mass can only be achieved by conversion of energy to mass through massive amounts of energy. This explains his high number (although realistically the number would have to be even higher to explain it via E= mc<sup>2</sup>).

> "In Speed, Hulk can jump a long distances, since this answer based on comics, you should consider that and I think that makes his speed more than 473."

This answer is based on a Marvel article using their stated number for the movie version. Because in the comics the Hulk has moved at the Speed of Thought (a speed of 31.56*10<sup>27</sup> times the speed of light), but that is just ridiculous and is based on what the writers need at that moment. The movie Hulk has a ground mobility of over 400 mph. Which I still find absolutely impressive. A 1150 pounds heavy angry Hulk running at you at over 400 mph? You wouldn't like that. Maybe you want him to be faster, just so it would be over faster.

Comment: ... based on Marvel statistics of March 11, 2019. Where is this data, whats the source? Please add it ..

Comment: My bad. The source has been added now.

Comment: Great answer! Proved Thor is still greatest Avenger.

Comment: How do you get from an article saying that Captain Marvel is the strongest Avenger (in the title, literally) to claiming that Thor is the strongest?

Comment: @Obie2.0 I have added an explanation as to why the article has a misleading title and a ranking to show how I came to the conclusion to say that Thor has the strongest energy blast. (Not the strongest in strength, because that would be the Hulk)

Comment: Also, the article seems to be based on comics information.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I'm not sure that is entirely true, but the information is in there. But let's face it. These are fictitious characters with fictitious powers. Their powers are whatever the writer and situation need them to be at that moment. We can argue endlessly about what looks stronger, unless we have numbers to back it up. This article literally compares Captain Marvel with the other heroes, is written by Marvel, published very recently and with quantifiable numbers for the characters in question. That seemed a good source to me, but I respect it if anyone thinks differently.

Comment: @GeorgeDerpi **Energy output** for Cap being zero seems weird. compared to others, Hulk doesn't have any energy beam or anything, just like Cap. but him having a huge number and Cap having zero is unclear to me why. In **Speed**, Hulk can jump a long distances, since this answer based on comics, you should consider that and I think that makes his speed more than 473. **strategy** and **Intelligence** levels are not correct IMHO

Comment: @Vishwa Once again, I did not come up with these numbers myself. They are from the Marvel article. But I have added another edit to my answer to possibly explain the numbers. Strategy I believe to be quite correct. Intelligence is difficult to say. Every hero has made some questionable decisions :) But everything depends on the source material. So I am both right and wrong at the same time.